# Best way to add more options to Gutenberg "More Rich" text controls drop down

Tags: php, block-editor

Can somebody point me in the right direction for adding more options to this gutenberg toggle. I would like to add some custom options that apply my own custom class.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: It's called the Format API. The Wordpress docs have [a pretty good writeup](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/format-api/), though their example doesn't scale to more options very well.